# Converting SSRS from Native Mode to SharePoint Integrated Mode

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am trying to follow [this article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh833726(v=office.14).aspx) to convert an SSRS instance from Native Mode to SharePoint Integrated Mode.

I am stuck at section “Configure SSRS in SharePoint integrated mode”, step 9. As you can see by my screenshot, the option to change the Report Server Mode is disabled.

My SSRS instance is SQL Server 2012 SP1  Enterprise Edition.

[image: Screenshot of SSRS Report Server Data Config Wizard]

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like a [separate instance of SSRS for SharePoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg492276.aspx#bkmk_install_SSRS_sharedservice) is required for SQL Server 2012.

[image: Choosing a separate instance of SSRS for SharePoint]

Comment: As a quick note for SQL 2014 - SharePoint integrated mode is not supported in the "Express" version - only native.