# SharePoint Integrated mode not shown while installing new instannce

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I need to convert SSRS Native mode to SharePoint Integrated mode. Similar Question was asked here [Converting SSRS from Native Mode to SharePoint Integrated Mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21273250/converting-ssrs-from-native-mode-to-sharepoint-integrated-mode). As a resolution I followed [this blog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg492276.aspx#bkmk_install_SSRS_sharedservice).

As per this blog, I need to add new instance of SSRS in sharepoint mode.
But it's not showing me **Reporting Services - Sharepoint** option in feature selection window while installing. Any help will be appriciated.

SQL Version: SQL Server 2014
SharePoint: SP2013

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it out. The problem was with the SQl Server 2014 setup.
I was installing **SQL Server 2014 Standard edition** where there is no provision of SSRS in SharePoint Integratde mode.

Later I installed **SQL Server 2014 Enterprise edition**  and now I can see the SharePoint integrated mode of SSRS while feature installation.